# Does edge contraction increases the degree of a regular graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Definition: A contraction of an edge represents the merging of the coalitions associated to its incident vertices.
Definition: A graph G is said to be regular, if all its vertices have the same degree.

It is trivial that contraction of any edge in a cycle $C_n$, $n \geq 4$ retains the degree of the graph.

Is there any regular graph different from $C_n$, $n \geq 4$ such that the graph obtained by contracting any edge is still regular?

Comment: Well, $n = 3$ works as well. If you contract an edge in a $C_3 \simeq K_3$, the resulting graph is the $P_2$ which is 1-regular.

Answer (score 1):

The only examples are:

1. A complete graph $K_n$. It is $(n-1)$-regular; after contracting an edge, what is left is $K_{n-1}$, which is $(n-2)$-regular.
2. A union of disjoint cycles, slightly generalizing your example. May contain infinite paths as special cases of "cycle" if you allow infinite graphs.
3. A graph completely without edges. This may or may not count, depending on how we parse your the word "any" in your condition. If it encodes a "for all edges", the edgeless graph vacuously satisfies the condition.

To see that these are all the possibilities, suppose that an $n$-regular graph has at least 3 vertices and has at least one edge that we can contract to produce another regular graph.  After contracting, every vertex that was *not* incident to the contracted edge has degree either $n$ or $n-1$.

If the contracted graph is $(n-1)$-regular. Then every *other* vertex must have been connected to *both* ends of the edge we contracted, and there must be exactly $n-1$ of them for the endpoints to have had degree $n$. So the graph had $n+1$ vertices and the only way for it to be $n$-regular was for it to be complete.

On the other hand, if the contracted graph is still $n$-regular it means that there was *no* vertex that was connected to both ends of the edge. Therefore the contracted vertex now has degree $2(n-1)$. But this needs to equal $n$, and $2(n-1)=n$ implies $n=2$, so the graph was a *union of disjoint cycles*.

This analysis does not consider graphs with fewer than 3 vertices, but they are either $K_2$ (and contracting its single edge produces a $0$-regular point) or are edgeless, so there are no new cases there.

Comment: $K_n$ also may or may not count, depending on whether contracting an edge which is part of a triangle should produce a multigraph or a simple graph.